# UISplitViewController: Abandoned memory until another VC is pushed into the navigation stack?

Tags: ios, abandoned-memory

I've been memory profiling an app I am working on and noticed that the detail view controller in my application is 'abandoned' (still resident in memory, but a valid reference still exists) until a new view controller is pushed onto the navigation stack.  I have tested this on-device and in-simulator and experience the same issue.

I created a sample project [here](https://github.com/waynehartman/AbandonedSplitViewController) and a video demonstrating the phenomenon [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-NP9AcccIi0).  In `dealloc` of the detail view controller I put a log message of when the view controller is destroyed.  This doesn't execute until after the new view controller is placed onto the navigation stack.

Doing a memory profile, the view controller isn't deallocated until a private method inside `UISplitViewController` is called, `_willShowCollapsedDetailViewController:inTargetController:`:

[image]

Is there something I am missing?  Is this a bug?  If not, how do I ensure that the detail view controller is properly deallocated when popped off the navigation stack?

This problem exists in iOS 8 *and* 9.

Answer (score 0):

When collapsed, `_willShowCollapsedDetailViewController` retains the detail controller via `_setPreservedDetailController` so it can be moved to the secondary position when separating the controllers in a rotation to landscape during `separateSecondaryViewControllerFromPrimaryViewController`. Otherwise the right side of the split view would be empty grey and sad looking. So what you are experiencing is when it preserves the new one, the previous is released and dealloced.